# What commands do you use with Laravel + Inertia to run an SSR server?

Tags: laravel, server-side-rendering, inertiajs

I have a **Laravel + Inertia + VueJS app**. I want to use **SSR** (**server-side rendering**) for better SEO.

The commands I have used until now (with Inertia, but without **SSR**) have been these:

- `npm run dev` (to run the front-end server)
- `php artisan serve` (to run the back-end server)

The [Inertia documentation](https://www.inertiajs.com/server-side-rendering) on SSR tells me I should run these commands:

- `npm run build` (to prepare the assets)
- `php artisan inertia:start-ssr` (to start the server using SSR)

When I use the last two commands, here is what happens:

- When I go to port `8000`, I get a this message in my browser: `Unable to connect`.
- When I go to port `13714`, I get a JSON array: `status "NOT_FOUND"`

After reading the documentation, I'm still confused. I must be missing something. What am I doing wrong here? What commands and port should I use?

**Edit:**

Also, when on top of that I run my usual `php artisan serve` command, my content is served on port `8000`, but as JS, not as actual HTML.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer to my question. This has worked **locally** for me and should also work remotely assuming you follow the same steps I describe.

When using SSR, you need to run this command first to make sure your content is up to date:

`npm run build`

Then you need to open **two** Terminal windows and use these **two** commands and run **two** different servers:

`php artisan serve`

`php artisan inertia:start-ssr`

Then, you go to your usual port (typically `8000`), so your URL should look like `http://localhost:8000/`.

Now, if you look at the source code, you should see HTML at the very end. To see this clearly, I recommend using **Chrome** instead of **Firefox** because it has a text wrapping feature at the top of the source code, with a checkbox.

If you kill the second server (the SSR one), you won't have HTML rendering, but your app should work fine besides that.

Your meta tags should be outputted as HTML as well when using SSR.